# Searching for an Alpha-Numeric code within a string

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to search through a column of freetext for the following - an 8 digit code, starting with an `F` and followed by seven digits - e.g `F1234567.` These can be located anywwhere in the string, which is of variable length. I have attempted this:

```
case when [SHORT-DESCRIPTION] like '%[0-9]%' then 1 end --finds integers
case when [SHORT-DESCRIPTION] like '%F%' then 1 end --finds the letter F
```

This seemed like the next logical step, but my syntax is wrong

```
case when [SHORT-DESCRIPTION] like '%F' & '%[0-9]%' then 1 end
```

It returned the following error:

```
The data types varchar and varchar are incompatible in the '&' operator.
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction? I'm using SQL Server 2008 R2.

Thanks,

Comment: & is an operator and it wont work in case conditions replace it with 'AND' @oliverLockett

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I first thought of Regular Expressions, but those are not fully supported in SQL 2008 yet. However, you can achieve your goal with normal pattern matching (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187489(SQL.90).aspx).

I've tested this and this works:

```
like '%F[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]%'
```

Comment: Why are you calling this "CLR pattern matching"? It has nothing to do with CLR...

Comment: Good point Aaron, I think I just picked that up from an earlier link when I looked this up. I've edited the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use  `LIKE '%[a-z0-9]%` insted of `'%[0-9]%'` or `'%F%'`

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
WHEN LEN([SHORT-DESCRIPTION]) = 8 AND 

     PATINDEX('%[A-Z]%',[SHORT-DESCRIPTION]) = 1 AND 

     ISNUMERIC(SUBSTRING([SHORT-DESCRIPTION],2,8)) = 1 

     THEN 1 -- Alpha Numeric (F1234567)
```